# how to get items from an javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I cant figure out, how to get items from this JSON. Please, can you help me? I have tried for example JSON.stringify or taken variable and written variable.items or variable.responseJSON.items...but it always doesnt work. Thank you very much.

[JSON response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1CGK.png)

EDIT:

responseText:

{…}
​
abort: function abort(e)
​
always: function always()
​
catch: function catch(e)
​
done: function add()
​
fail: function add()
​
getAllResponseHeaders: function getAllResponseHeaders()
​
getResponseHeader: function getResponseHeader(e)
​
overrideMimeType: function overrideMimeType(e)
​
pipe: function pipe()
​
progress: function add()
​
promise: function promise(e)
​
readyState: 4
​
responseJSON: Object { items: (6) […] }
​
responseText: "{\n  "items": [\n    {\n      "id": "WibQCYgmb8w",\n      "snippet": {\n        "title": "27 8  Kněhyně štafeta dvojic starší žáci 1 pokus",\n        "thumbnails": {\n          "default": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WibQCYgmb8w/default.jpg",\n            "width": 120,\n            "height": 90\n          },\n          "medium": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WibQCYgmb8w/mqdefault.jpg",\n            "width": 320,\n            "height": 180\n          },\n          "high": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WibQCYgmb8w/hqdefault.jpg",\n            "width": 480,\n            "height": 360\n          },\n          "standard": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WibQCYgmb8w/sddefault.jpg",\n            "width": 640,\n            "height": 480\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    },\n    {\n      "id": "1RmUpp_iryc",\n      "snippet": {\n        "title": "27 8  Kněhyně štafeta dvojic starší žáci 2 pokus",\n        "thumbnails": {\n          "default": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1RmUpp_iryc/default.jpg",\n            "width": 120,\n            "height": 90\n          },\n          "medium": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1RmUpp_iryc/mqdefault.jpg",\n            "width": 320,\n            "height": 180\n          },\n          "high": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1RmUpp_iryc/hqdefault.jpg",\n            "width": 480,\n            "height": 360\n          },\n          "standard": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1RmUpp_iryc/sddefault.jpg",\n            "width": 640,\n            "height": 480\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    },\n    {\n      "id": "IQsrulcu5r4",\n      "snippet": {\n        "title": "27 8  Kněhyně štafeta dvojic mladší žáci 1 pokus",\n        "thumbnails": {\n          "default": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IQsrulcu5r4/default.jpg",\n            "width": 120,\n            "height": 90\n          },\n          "medium": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IQsrulcu5r4/mqdefault.jpg",\n            "width": 320,\n            "height": 180\n          },\n          "high": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IQsrulcu5r4/hqdefault.jpg",\n            "width": 480,\n            "height": 360\n          },\n          "standard": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IQsrulcu5r4/sddefault.jpg",\n            "width": 640,\n            "height": 480\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    },\n    {\n      "id": "F7F54YirWSs",\n      "snippet": {\n        "title": "27 8  Kněhyně štafeta dvojic mladší žáci 2 pokus",\n        "thumbnails": {\n          "default": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/F7F54YirWSs/default.jpg",\n            "width": 120,\n            "height": 90\n          },\n          "medium": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/F7F54YirWSs/mqdefault.jpg",\n            "width": 320,\n            "height": 180\n          },\n          "high": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/F7F54YirWSs/hqdefault.jpg",\n            "width": 480,\n            "height": 360\n          },\n          "standard": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/F7F54YirWSs/sddefault.jpg",\n            "width": 640,\n            "height": 480\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    },\n    {\n      "id": "rMJ-eJWXXQQ",\n      "snippet": {\n        "title": "27 8  Kněhyně požární útok mladší žáci 1 pokus",\n        "thumbnails": {\n          "default": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rMJ-eJWXXQQ/default.jpg",\n            "width": 120,\n            "height": 90\n          },\n          "medium": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rMJ-eJWXXQQ/mqdefault.jpg",\n            "width": 320,\n            "height": 180\n          },\n          "high": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rMJ-eJWXXQQ/hqdefault.jpg",\n            "width": 480,\n            "height": 360\n          },\n          "standard": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rMJ-eJWXXQQ/sddefault.jpg",\n            "width": 640,\n            "height": 480\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    },\n    {\n      "id": "INi4Dvh2ozI",\n      "snippet": {\n        "title": "27 8  Kněhyně požární útok mladší žáci 2 pokus",\n        "thumbnails": {\n          "default": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/INi4Dvh2ozI/default.jpg",\n            "width": 120,\n            "height": 90\n          },\n          "medium": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/INi4Dvh2ozI/mqdefault.jpg",\n            "width": 320,\n            "height": 180\n          },\n          "high": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/INi4Dvh2ozI/hqdefault.jpg",\n            "width": 480,\n            "height": 360\n          },\n          "standard": {\n            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/INi4Dvh2ozI/sddefault.jpg",\n            "width": 640,\n            "height": 480\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  ]\n}\n"
​
setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader(e, t)
​
state: function state()
​
status: 200
​
statusCode: function statusCode(e)
​
statusText: "OK"
​
then: function then(t, r, i)
​
: Object { … }
videogalerie.php:257:14

Comment: Why `JSON.stringify()` when it's already JSON?

Comment: Try JSON.parse(responseText). Please share the complete responseText so that we can let you know, how exactly it will work.

Comment: JSON.parse says this: Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: Please share the string of responseText

Comment: You are getting Uncaught SyntaxError error because your value is starting with double quote and internally also it has double quotes. take the value of responseText, and it should start with single quote. replace double quote with single quote. then do try.parse().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the object, I assume this is a result of a jquery's ajax call.

Probably `variable.responseJSON.items` doesn't work always because the call is async, so my educated guess is that you're not call it from the proper callback, or maybe the ajax's call returns an error.

For example, something like that:

```
let mycall = $.ajax({
  url: 'mydata.json',
  dataType: 'json',
);

console.dir(myCall.responseJSON.items);
```

Won't work. You should have something like:

```
let mycall = $.ajax({
  url: 'mydata.json',
  dataType: 'json',
).done(function() {
  console.dir(myCall.responseJSON.items);
});
```

See: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Oh thanks, this was one mistake. But it still dont work properly. U use this now:  videosInfo = $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=API_KEY&part=snippet&fields=items(id,snippet(title, thumbnails))&id=" + videoIDs).done(function(){console.log(videosInfo.items);
console.log(videosInfo); and videosInfo.items says "undefined".

Comment: Forgotten to write there responseJSON. Now it works. Thank you very much!